# Using Two Get's In One Command

Tags: powershell

We are trying to create a login script that will export the results of a script that spits out the current logged in user as well as the mapped drives that they have. The problem lies in running two "Get-'s".

I have tried different variations all of which either output nothing or just one command. This code is kind of what I need but it does not output what I need it to.

`Get-CimInstance -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select "UserName" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append \\sn01\installs\test\test.csv ; Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select "Name" , "ProviderName" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -append \\sn01\installs\test\test.csv -Force`

The first half is what I want to output the username and then the second half is what I expect to output the letter of the drive as well as the path of that drive.

Ideally what I need is three columns titled Username, Name, ProviderName that contains their username, drive letter and then the drive path.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
$user = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk |
    Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$user.Username}},Name ,ProviderName |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path \\sn01\installs\test\test.csv -Force
```

**Explanation:**

You can store the output of `Get-CimInstance` object with `Username` property into variable `$user`. When you are executing your second `Select-Object` statement, you can use a calculated property `Username` and retrieve the value from the `$user.Username` property.

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing, thank you so much.